# Print dict items in alphabet order

Tags: python, xml, xbmc

I'm working on my python script to dict the channels items every time when the items is inserted by using this code:

```
channels = {}
for elem in tv_elem.getchildren():
    if elem.tag == 'channel':
       channels[elem.attrib['id']] = self.load_channel(elem)
       for channel_key in channels:
           channel = channels[channel_key]
           display_name = channel.get_display_name()
           print display_name
```

Here is what it print out:

```
20:58:02 T:6548  NOTICE: BBC One UK EN
20:58:02 T:6548  NOTICE: SVT 1 SE SE
20:58:02 T:6548  NOTICE: National Geographic Channel UK EN
20:58:02 T:6548  NOTICE: NRK1 NO NO
20:58:02 T:6548  NOTICE: Discovery Channel UK EN
20:58:02 T:6548  NOTICE: ARD DE DE
20:58:02 T:6548  NOTICE: DR1 DK DK
```

Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<tv generator-info-name="www.timefor.tv/xmltv">
        <channel id="www.timefor.tv/tv/162">
            <display-name lang="de">ARD DE DE</display-name>
        </channel>
        <channel id="www.timefor.tv/tv/1">
            <display-name lang="dk">DR1 DK DK</display-name>
        </channel>
        <channel id="www.timefor.tv/tv/130">
            <display-name lang="no">NRK1 NO NO</display-name>
        </channel>
        <channel id="www.timefor.tv/tv/135">
            <display-name lang="se">SVT 1 SE SE</display-name>
        </channel>
        <channel id="www.timefor.tv/tv/10769">
            <display-name lang="en">BBC One UK EN</display-name>
        </channel>
        <channel id="www.timefor.tv/tv/10214">
            <display-name lang="en">National Geographic Channel UK EN</display-name>
        </channel>
        <channel id="www.timefor.tv/tv/10847">
            <display-name lang="en">Discovery Channel UK EN</display-name>
        </channel></tv>
```

I want to print them in the same alphabet order as the XML file, what I have print it is not in the same order as the XML file. Do you know how I can print the items in the same alphabet order as the XML file using my code?

Comment: A `dict` is essentially unordered. Try using an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: It doesn't seem that the xml file is sorted alphabetically (either by `tv/xxxxx` or `display-name`.  Is this intended?

Comment: @mogambo thank you for your advice. Could you please post the source of the OrderedDict with my code that I should use?

Comment: Do you want the same ordering as the XML, or do you want to sort the channels by display name?

Comment: And should `for channel in channels` be inside the other `for` loop? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You could just use a list if order rather than lookup is important

Comment: @SteinarLima yes I'd want the same ordering as the XML, but if that is not possible then listing the channels in OrderedDict would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you've explained:

```
#Additional import
from collections import OrderedDict
channels = OrderedDict()
for elem in tv_elem.getchildren():
    if elem.tag == 'channel':
       channels[elem.attrib['id']] = self.load_channel(elem)
       for channel_value in channels.items():
           print channel_value.get_display_name()
```

**NOTE**: This will give you the same order as you read them from the XML, **not** alphabetical

**EDIT :** Since you're using Python 2.6, a small workaround:

```
channels = []
for elem in tv_elem.getchildren():
    if elem.tag == 'channel':
       channels.append( (elem.attrib['id'], self.load_channel(elem)) )
       for channel_value in channels:
           print channel_value[1].get_display_name()
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I have got a problem. I have got an error `from collections import OrderedDict ImportError: cannot import name OrderedDict.` I don't know why I have got an error? I'm using python 2.6 version for xbmc.

Comment: Unfortunately, `OrderedDict` was introduced in Python 2.7. I guess you'll have to use nested lists.

Comment: OrderedDict was added to the `collections` module in Python 2.7. http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict Use this recipe if you're using Python 2.6: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/

Comment: @IceArdor Thank you very much for your help. It have helping me to solve the problem. I have got the list of items that are in perfect  alphabet order as the XML file.

Answer (score 1):

Update: mogambo got in first while I was typing :)

Replace first line with

```
from collections import OrderedDict
channels = OrderedDict()
```

I would only add: you might just as well append your channel objects to a list, if you never need to retrieve them individually by id and only want to iterate over them in the same order as they appeared in the XML.

Comment: scav is correct in stating that if you don't need constant-time lookup to an individual item in your dictionary then you might as well use a list, which is more memory efficient.